# Setting member variable in a private method or outside?

Tags: java, coding-style, swt

I have a basic coding practice question. Which among these is a good practice.

```
private Text myTextControl;

public void createControl()
{
   createTextControl(parent,2,2);
}

private void createTextControl(Composite parent, int horizontalSpan, int verticalSpan)
{
   myTextControl = new Text(parent,SWT.SINGLE);
   GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, horizontalSpan,
                         verticalSpan);
   myTextControl.setLayoutData(layoutData);
}
```

**OR**

```
public void createControl()
{
   myTextControl = createTextControl(parent,2,2);
}

private Text createTextControl(Composite parent, int horizontalSpan, int verticalSpan)
{
   Text text = new Text(parent,SWT.SINGLE);
   GridData layoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, horizontalSpan,
                         verticalSpan);
   text.setLayoutData(layoutData);
   return text;
}
```

I'm confused whether any one is better than the other. So just wanted to make sure

Comment: Your first choice, solely on that it is easier to read and follow. IMHO

Comment: I honestly don't think this is answerable without seeing the entire class from which this is extracted.  Normally "self-contained" methods  whose effects are all in a function result, as opposed to modifying fields defined outside the method, are slightly preferable.  But here I think it depends on how `myTextControl` is used in the rest of your class.  Either one could read better depending on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you continue to use the same function createTextControl that returns a Text object, you should use the second code statement, as it would be a waste to return it and not use it.  Also, the second one allows for more code re-usability.

Comment: What about now? I have made the method in first case as void

Comment: Please don't change the question in a substantial way after it is posted.

Comment: @EricJ. Sorry I just made the return type of createTextControl to void. It won't affect anything

Comment: @Vwin Well, after your edit, I think the second variant is better because the first one no longer compiles.

Comment: @ajb sorry about that. Made the change

Comment: @Vwin: My answer was no longer relevant after your edit.  It did change things.  It would have been better to add a third variant.

Comment: @EricJ.: Why was that? I just changed the return type of createControl which is eventually not doing anything after it returns.Sorry about that. But this is my final edit. Can you help me now?

Comment: @Vwin: My answer was *The second variant introduces side-effects. That is, it makes modifications to the state that are not obvious from the method signature.*  That's no longer true after the change. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: @EricJ.: I did not change the anything to the second variant. I changed the first option. But thanks for the link. I will give it a read

Comment: @Vwin to answer your question from the first comment: It is a matter of preference in a lot of ways, but if you are going to use this function elsewhere, you should use the second.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view, your second code is better in this case, because the `createControl` class must to used to creat all types of controll and inside it you have to call other methods that will create an specific control like the `textControl`